# How to transition data in a JSONB column in to separate columns for millions of rows in Rails/Postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I've got a JSONB column in Postgres and I need to split out the JSONB data into individual columns. I've got all the new columns set up, but now I've got about 3 million records whose JSONB data needs to get split out into individual columns.

What's the most performant way to basically run an UPDATE on every single row?

Right now I'm doing this inside a Rails rake task:

```rb
Track.all.find_each do |track|
  track.update_attributes(
    key: track.audio_features['key'],
    mode: track.audio_features['mode'],
    tempo: track.audio_features['tempo'],
    energy: track.audio_features['energy'],
    valence: track.audio_features['valence'],
    liveness: track.audio_features['liveness'],
    loudness: track.audio_features['loudness'],
    speechiness: track.audio_features['speechiness'],
    acousticness: track.audio_features['acousticness'],
    danceability: track.audio_features['danceability'],
    time_signature: track.audio_features['time_signature'],
    instrumentalness: track.audio_features['instrumentalness'],
  )
end
```

That...will take a while for 3 million rows. Is there a faster way to do that?

Comment: Compose a query in plain SQL instead.

Comment: The first answer given may be a great one (I'm not familiar with the subject), but  awarding it with the green checkmark so quickly may discourage other answers.  As you know, there's no rush to make a selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with SQL directly instead of creating everything in Ruby. This won't run validations or callbacks that your Ruby models would have in place, so will be a bit more dangerous, but it would be much faster.

The SQL syntax would look something like:

```sql
UPDATE tracks 
SET key = audio_features->>'key',
  mode = audio_features->>'mode',
  energy = audio_features->>'energy',
  valence = audio_features->>'valence',
  liveness = audio_features->>'liveness',
  loudness = audio_features->>'loudness',
  speechiness = audio_features->>'speechiness',
  acousticness = audio_features->>'acousticness',
  danceability = audio_features->>'danceability',
  time_signature = audio_features->>'time_signature',
  instrumentalness = audio_features->>'instrumentalness';
```

Comment: I would add something like a temporary 'migrated' boolean column and flip it to true in the update so that you can resume the update without updating the same records again.

Comment: Ran this and it ultimately did the trick! Took a little over an hour to run. Thanks!